# UV-Vis and Polylactid Acid (PLA)

Tags: everyday-chemistry, spectrophotometry, plastics

I am trying to use UV-VIS for a 3D printed ~4mm PLA design. However I keep running into a problem because the polymer is not showing detectable under the UV-VIS. Does anyone have any suggestions that would allow for visibility of PLA? Any recommended papers would be of great use as well.

I also thought of possibly placing spider silk inside but this would implement an array of complexity in the product.

Thanks guys

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Find out how to beautify your posts in the [help center](/help) and take the [tour] to learn more about this site. Enjoy!

Comment: Based on your question, I think you're trying to estimate the UV/Vis absorption of the PLA sample? What wavelength range are you examining?

Comment: The wavelength was between 200 and 800. We could not see any data form between 400 and 800 nm